# Why doesn't Tailwind CSS consistenly use `@media not all and (min-width: )` but mixes `@media not all and (min-width: )` with `@media (max-width: )`?

Tags: tailwind-css

For example:

- `max-md` generates `@media not all and (min-width: 768px)`:
  [image: image example]
- `max-[768px]` generates `@media (max-width: 768px)`  :
  [image: image example]

This causes confusion. I think `max-md` and `max-[768px]` should both generate either `@media` not all and `(min-width: 768px)` or `@media (max-width: 768px)`, so they'll be considered same type in media queries to achieve consistency.

Comment: I assume you mean to ask whether there is any benefit in going either way, or whether there are subtle differences you are not aware of. In that case I'd recommend you to add this to your question to avoid people downvoting your question based on the fact that a "Why does X do Y" question should better be asked X's authors and not us if you are just interested in their thoughts in that particular case and not a general answer.

Comment: @CherryDT What do you mean by adding "this" to my question?  Should I delete this question and put it in Tailwind CSS's github issue page?

Comment: I meant to specify the question better, like what I wrote in the first sentence - if that's what you wanted to know.

Answer (score 2):

Tailwind consistently uses `min-width` values for its breakpoint prefixes. e.g. `md`, `lg` etc.

https://tailwindcss.com/docs/responsive-design

In the second example you are using 'Arbitrary values' and explicitly setting a `max-width` breakpoint with `max-[768px]:`. If you want to use `min` then you can use `min-[768px]:` which would be the same as using `md:`.

https://tailwindcss.com/docs/responsive-design#arbitrary-values

The `max-md` you are using is designed for targeting a single breakpoint. See the section "Targeting a breakpoint range".

Comment: I found it inappropriate to put this question on stack overflow, so I move it to github: https://github.com/tailwindlabs/tailwindcss/discussions/11391
I want to delete this question, but I was told I don't have permission because someone else had already answered the question. Could you remove your answer so I can delete this question?

Comment: Have I not answered your question? What is still not clear? It is a valid question to ask here and two people have already marked the answer as useful.

Comment: What is still not resolved is, I want Tailwind"s developers to consider changing the code as what I said in the description of the question. If they think it's unnecessary , they should explain why. This is also the reason why I think this question should be put on Tailwind's github discussions page.